# How to enable the Translate contextual menu in my edittext?

Tags: android, textview, android-6.0-marshmallow

On marshmallow their is now a contextual menu "translate" when we select some text :

[image]

The problem, i don't know why, i can't see this option in my application when i select text in my textview. What i need to do to activate it ?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29 try this and of course, make sure latest Google translate app is installed. Also you mentioned, you have selected text in `TextView`? I believe it might only work in `EditText`. Try that out as well

Comment: thanks th3pat3l however, i don't understand but i still can't see the translate (but on other app i can see it). and as they say at  
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/ Android apps that use Android text selection behavior will already have this feature enabled, and i use android text selection ... so i don't understand what i missed :( maybe i need to install some library ?

Comment: What do you mean you use android text selection? I would recommend add an `EditText` in your app and see if the option come there. From what I understand, there is no lib to install

Comment: yes exactly, it's an EditText that i use, but i can't see the "translate" option :(

Answer (score -4):

Used in ListView? 
Like this

```
MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listMap);
```

try to this

```
MyBaseAdapter baseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(this, listMap);
```

if you are `new TextView(context)` reference this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html